# Update Android Studio from 3.6 to 4.0 fails with error

Tags: android

The update to Android Studio 4.0 gives me the following error on Windows 10:

> Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues
>   com.intellij.ide.plugins.MainRunner$StartupAbortedException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at com.intellij.ide.plugins.MainRunner.lambda$start$0(MainRunner.java:61)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at com.intellij.ide.plugins.MainRunner.lambda$start$0(MainRunner.java:58)
>       ... 1 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/channel/ChannelHandler at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.lockSystemFolders(StartupUtil.java:478) at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.lockDirsAndConfigureLogger(StartupUtil.java:252) at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.prepareAndStart(StartupUtil.java:184) at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.java:16)
>       ... 6 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.netty.channel.ChannelHandler at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.findClass(UrlClassLoader.java:282) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>       ... 10 more

---

```
JRE 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04 amd64 by JetBrains s.r.o
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre"
```

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues does not open.

Any idea to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem in the android studio in **Linux OS** after installing a plugin, I resolved this issue with deleted.AndroidStudio4.0 folder from Home Directory and other ways you can go to this directory and delete the last installed plugin that caused it.

**Directory** : /home/your system's name/.AndroidStudio4.0/config/plugins .

and for **Windows**

**Directory** : C:\Users\your system's name.AndroidStudioPreview4.0\config\plugins

**Note**: this directory is hidden and you must visible before use it.